# Get constructor parameter values using scala reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-macros, scala-reflect

Working in a codebase with scala that wants you, for certain classes, to define a sort of "make a new version" - so for instance if you have a class x(a :int, b:String, c:double)... it would have a function like this:

```
class x( a: Integer, b : String, c : Double) extends CanMakeNew
{
    def newValue() = x( a, b, c)
}
```

I have no control over that - but would prefer not to implement it every time.  Or, well... ever.  Is there a way in scala, with reflection - to iterate over the constructor parameter values?   I can use reflection to look at the parameter *types* - but as parameternames has not been turned on for this module, and I can't turn it on - I can't correlate those with the stored values in the class.   Fundamentally, I'm looking for anyway of implementing a trait like:

```
trait CanMakeNewDoneForMe extends CanMakeNew {
    def newValue()  {I need the code that goes here}
```

So does scala reflection have any way of either inspecting the constructor or inspecting the object and seeing "ahh, this was the third parameter in the constructor"?

Comment: What is the reason `newValue()` can't simply return `this`? Does `x` contain any mutable state that would make returning the same instance a problem?

Comment: yes - x contains heaps of mutable state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make `X` a case class it will have `apply`, `copy`... generated by compiler automatically.

> And basically it’s not my codebase, so I can’t really change any of the shape of things...

When you make a class a case class you don't actually "change shape of things", you just add autogenerated methods.

Anyway, you can create a macro annotation that generates method `newValue`.

```
  import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
  import scala.language.experimental.macros
  import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

  class newValue extends StaticAnnotation {
    def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro newValueMacro.impl
  }

  object newValueMacro {
    def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
      import c.universe._
      annottees match {
        case q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }" :: tail =>
          val tparams1 = tparams.map {
            case q"$_ type $name[..$_] >: $_ <: $_" => tq"$name"
          }
          val paramss1 = paramss.map(_.map {
            case q"$_ val $pat: $_ = $_" => pat
          })
          q"""
              $mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self =>
                def newValue() = new $tpname[..$tparams1](...$paramss1)
                ..$stats
              }

              ..$tail
            """

        case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "not a class")
      }

    }
  }

  @newValue
  /*case*/ class X(a: Int, b : String, c : Double) {
    override def toString: String = s"X($a, $b, $c)"
  }

  val x = new X(1, "a", 2.0) //X(1, a, 2.0)
  //  val x1 = x.copy()
  val x1 = x.newValue() //X(1, a, 2.0)
```

Comment: ok - that's very cool - I'll have to take some time to understand it :)    Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I might be wrong here, but usually this is achieved using pattern matching and the `apply()` and `unapply()` methods defined in your companion object.

I've done a small test of your above code in a REPL session. I didn't understand the purpose of the `newvalue()` function so I skipped it.

```
class x(val a: Integer, val b : String, val c : Double)
{
  //def newValue() = x( a, b, c)
}

object x {
  def apply(a: Integer, b: String, c: Double): x = new x(a,b,c)
  def unapply(m: x): Option[(Integer, String, Double)] = Some((m.a, m.b, m.c))
}

x(1, "hello", 99.0d) match {
  case l: x => println(s"this the the 3rd arg in the constructor: ${l.c}")
}
```

The `unapply()` function def above allows the pattern match deconstruct on the object.
The alternative is to use a `case class` to define class `x` (this will define the `apply()` and `unapply()` functions for you).

Comment: Sorry I wasn’t clear.   The question is - how do I implement the newvalue function in a generic way - that’s the only thing that matters.

Comment: @DarrenOakey Why can't you make `X` a **case** class? It has `apply`, `copy`... generated by compiler automatically.

Comment: Because I haven’t shown the whole picture - these are all service classes that get initialised into an environment, and the function exists so they can get initialised into another environment.   And basically it’s not my codebase, so I can’t really change any of the shape of things - I just want to find a clever way of not having to code that function by hand every time - and i can’t imagine a solution exists that doesn’t involve reflection :(